# Make tree menu one item at a time

Tags: javascript, menu, treeview, jstree

I've implemented a nice simple [tree menu script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/navigate1.htm#.UjsqFD__J8E), and would like very much to have only one item expanded at a time. The script does not come equipped with a switch for this, and I must admit that this is something I have no clue how to approach. I would greatly appreciate guidance.

You can see a stripped-down version my implementation [here](http://brettcolephotography.com/clients/dynamic-drive/tree.html). Note that as you click on disparate menu items the previous branches stay open unless you click to close them first. I would like to allow only one to be open at a time.

The script does use cookies to remember the menu state, so that when you visit several pages within a branch, the branch stays open when switching between pages, creating a smoother browsing experience. This feature can be disabled, but the overall behavior of two separate branches being allowed to remain open at once doesn't change.

Many thanks and I look forward to learning something new from this.

Comment: Did you find a solution?
I would also like to implement such function.